# In linq how to access properties of objects in a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to have this sql query done using entity framework and linq:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.ID as UserID, Users.FirstName, Users.Surname, Users.ADID 
FROM Users INNER JOIN Journals ON Users.ID = Journals.UserID
WHERE(((Journals.CompanyID) = {1})
```

So I need Users (User has a list of Journals) where in that Journals.Company.CompanyID (every Journal has a set Company) equals some CompanyID.

I'm struggling to create a linq query for this.

Comment: LEFT JOIN and add your conditions in your where ?

Comment: context.Users.Where(u=>u.Journals.CompanyID == id); If I imagine your data context correctly, the query should look like this.

Comment: Please post a sample of what you have tried.

Comment: The straightforward is to start with `from u in db.Users from j in u.Journals `, now you have access to `Journal` properties via variable `j`, e.g. `j.Company` etc.

Comment: didn't know about the join or using 2 "froms". How do I achieve the distinct values?

Comment: thanks. Also have another issue. Maybe should be a separate question. Part of the same query (it was using the MS Access "iif" statement).

`IIf([Journals].[Frequency] = 'Ad hoc' And [Journals].[AdHocRecoMonth] <> '{0}', 'NO', 'YES')) = 'YES'))`

So I need so If logic statement. If Journal.Frequency is AdHoc the Journal.AdHocRecoMonth must be the one provided.

Comment: you'll have good feedback if you put that on new question @GlutVonSmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.Here `db` is your context.

```
(from u in db.Users
join j in db.Journals on u.ID equals j.UserID
where j.CompanyID == 1
select u).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.Users.Where(u => u.Journals.Any(j => j.CompanyID == 1))
```

Is my preferred way as you don't need to use the distinct logic (which feels weird when working with objects)